# mi objeto no se dibuja en mi JFrame

Tags: java

amigos, tengo un problema, he creado mi propio objeto (llamado time_ligth), al agregarlo a mi JFrame, va todo bien, pero, a la hora de agregarle otro objeto(JButton o cualquier otro) solo se ve dibujado uno de ellos, como hago que se vean todos mis objetos

Posdata: ya intente agregarlos a un contenedor y darle Layouts pero ni asi se puede

este es mi clase main

```
import javax.swing.*;
import suemmyligth.time_ligth;
import suemmyligth.boton_ligth;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class main_Gui extends JFrame  {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("ventana");
    time_ligth time = new time_ligth(); 
    boton_ligth boton = new boton_ligth();

    f.setBounds(280,150,700,600);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    time.setPoints(20, 20, 200, 300); 
    time.setNumber(45);
    f.add(time);
    f.add(boton);

    f.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            time.setNumber(25);
            if(time.isPressed(e)==true) {

                time.setNumber(89); 

            }
            f.repaint(); 
        }
    });


    }
}
```

y este es el objeto time_ligth, hereda de la clase JPanel para dibujarse y usa la clase Graphics para dibujar sus componentes

```
package suemmyligth;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

//import java.applet.Applet;

/*
 * @author César Ricardo Lazcano Valdez
 */

public class time_ligth extends JPanel {

//Strings que manejan método setNumber
static String cadena, numLeft, numRigth; 
//componente para metodo isPressed
static MouseEvent e;        
//int de metodo setPoints
static int X,Y, ancho_total, alto_total, numero; 
static int rigth, left, roun1=20, roun2=20; 
//datos de getPoints
static int sizeX[], sizeY[];

static int n1ax, n1ay, n1a_ancho, n1a_alto;         //datos para los componentes
static int n2ax, n2ay, n2a_ancho, n2a_alto;
static int n3ax, n3ay, n3a_ancho, n3a_alto;
static int n4ax, n4ay, n4a_ancho, n4a_alto;
static int n5ax, n5ay, n5a_ancho, n5a_alto;
static int n6ax, n6ay, n6a_ancho, n6a_alto;
static int n7ax, n7ay, n7a_ancho, n7a_alto;

static int n1bx, n1by, n1b_ancho, n1b_alto;
static int n2bx, n2by, n2b_ancho, n2b_alto;
static int n3bx, n3by, n3b_ancho, n3b_alto;
static int n4bx, n4by, n4b_ancho, n4b_alto;
static int n5bx, n5by, n5b_ancho, n5b_alto;
static int n6bx, n6by, n6b_ancho, n6b_alto;
static int n7bx, n7by, n7b_ancho, n7b_alto;

/*Colores de manejo
 * colores principales
 * colores de inicio
 * */
static Color cuadrado_principal = new java.awt.Color(0,0,0); 
static Color ligth = new java.awt.Color(0,255,255) ;  
static Color neutro = new java.awt.Color(0,0,0) ;
static Color gris = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169);

static Color color_n1a = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169);       
static Color color_n2a = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n3a = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n4a = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n5a = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169);           
static Color color_n6a = color_n5a;
static Color color_n7a = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 

static Color color_n1b = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n2b = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n3b = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n4b = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n5b = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 
static Color color_n6b = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169);
static Color color_n7b = new java.awt.Color(169,169,169); 

//metodo que se encarga de dar las coordenadas y tamaños del objeto
public void setPoints(int x, int y, int ancho, int alto ) {         
    this.X=x;
    this.Y=y; 
    this.ancho_total=ancho;
    this.alto_total=alto;

    n1ax=(int)(X+((ancho_total/100)*6.25));         
    n1ay=(int)(Y+((alto_total/100)*5));
    n1a_ancho=(int)((ancho_total/100)*37.5); 
    n1a_alto=(int)((alto_total/100)*5); 

    n2ax=n1ax; 
    n2ay=(int)(Y+((alto_total/100)*10));
    n2a_ancho=(int)((ancho_total/100)*6.25);
    n2a_alto=(int)((alto_total/100)*35);

    n3ax=(int)(X+((ancho_total/100)*37.5)); 
    n3ay=(int)(Y+((alto_total/100)*10));
    n3a_ancho=n2a_ancho; 
    n3a_alto=n2a_alto; 

    n4ax=n1ax; 
    n4ay=(int)(Y+((alto_total/100)*45));
    n4a_ancho=n1a_ancho;
    n4a_alto=n1a_alto; 

    n5ax=n1ax; 
    n5ay=(int)(Y+((alto_total/100)*45));
    n5a_ancho=n2a_ancho;
    n5a_alto=n2a_alto;

    n6ax=n3ax;
    n6ay=n5ay;
    n6a_ancho=n3a_ancho;
    n6a_alto=n3a_alto;

    n7ax=n1ax;
    n7ay=(int)(Y+((alto_total/100)*80));
    n7a_ancho=n1a_ancho;
    n7a_alto=n1a_alto; 

    n1bx=(int)(X+((ancho_total/100)*56.25)); 
    n1by=n1ay; 
    n1b_ancho=n1a_ancho; 
    n1b_alto=n1a_alto; 

    n2bx=n1bx;
    n2by=n2ay; 
    n2b_ancho=n2a_ancho;
    n2b_alto=n2a_alto;

    n3bx=(int)(X+((ancho_total/100)*87.5));
    n3by=n2by;
    n3b_ancho=n2b_ancho;
    n3b_alto=n2b_alto;

    n4bx=n1bx;
    n4by=n4ay;
    n4b_ancho=n1b_ancho;
    n4b_alto=n1b_alto; 

    n5bx=n1bx;
    n5by=n5ay;
    n5b_ancho=n2b_ancho;
    n5b_alto=n2b_alto;

    n6bx=n3bx;
    n6by=(int)(Y+((alto_total/100)*45));
    n6b_ancho=n2b_ancho;
    n6b_alto=n5b_alto;

    n7bx=n1bx; 
    n7by=n7ay; 
    n7b_ancho=n1b_ancho;
    n7b_alto=n1b_alto; 

}


//retorna todas las coordenadas x que ocupada el reloj
public int[] getPointsX() {         

    int sizeX[]=new int[ancho_total+1];
    for (int i=X;i<=ancho_total+X; i++) {

        sizeX[i-X]=i; 


    }
    return sizeX;   
}

//metodo que retorna las posiciones en y del objeto
public int[] getPointsY() {

    int sizeY[]=new int[alto_total+1]; 

    for(int i=Y; i<=alto_total+Y; i++) {
        sizeY[i-Y]=i;   
    }
    return sizeY; 
}

/*metodo para saber si fue presionado o nel
 * este metodo sirv para darle la funcion al reloj de boton
 * los eventos deben ser administrados por la clase main de la siguiente manera:
 * import java.awt.event.*;
 * JFrame f = new JFrame();
 * f.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            time.setNumber(25);
            if(time.isPressed(e)==true) {
                eventos
            }
            f.repaint(); 
        }
    });
 * */
public boolean isPressed(MouseEvent E) {

    this.e=E;

    int positionX[]=getPointsX(); 
    int positionY[]=getPointsY();
    boolean mouseInX=false, mouseInY=false, pressed=false; 
    for(int i=0; i<=positionX.length-1; i++) {
        if(e.getX()==positionX[i]) {
            mouseInX=true;  
        }                   
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=positionY.length-1;i++) {
        if(e.getY()==positionY[i]) {
            mouseInY=true;
        } 
    }

    if(mouseInX == true && mouseInX== true) {
         pressed = true; 
    }

    return pressed; 

}


//método que hace iluminar el reloj para colocar un número
public void setNumber(int number){
    this.numero=number;


        cadena=String.valueOf(numero);

    if(cadena.length()>=2){
        numRigth=cadena.substring(cadena.length()-1,cadena.length()); 
        numLeft=cadena.substring(cadena.length()-2,cadena.length()-1); 

        rigth=Integer.parseInt(numRigth);
        left=Integer.parseInt(numLeft);

        switch(rigth){
            case 1:  

                    color_n1b=neutro;
                    color_n2b=neutro; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=neutro;
                    color_n5b=neutro; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=neutro; 

            break;
            case 2: 

                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=neutro; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=ligth;
                    color_n5b=ligth; 
                    color_n6b=neutro;
                    color_n7b=ligth; 

            break;
            case 3:
                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=neutro; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=ligth;
                    color_n5b=neutro; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=ligth; 
            break;
            case 4:
                    color_n1b=neutro;
                    color_n2b=ligth; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=ligth;
                    color_n5b=neutro; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=neutro; 
            break;
            case 5:
                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=ligth; 
                    color_n3b=neutro;
                    color_n4b=ligth;
                    color_n5b=neutro; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=ligth;
            break;
            case 6: 
                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=ligth; 
                    color_n3b=neutro;
                    color_n4b=ligth;
                    color_n5b=ligth; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=ligth;
            break;
            case 7:
                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=neutro; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=neutro;
                    color_n5b=neutro; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=neutro;
            break;
            case 8:
                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=ligth; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=ligth;
                    color_n5b=ligth; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=ligth;
            break;
            case 9:
                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=ligth; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=ligth;
                    color_n5b=neutro; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=ligth; 
            break;
            case 0:
                    color_n1b=ligth;
                    color_n2b=ligth; 
                    color_n3b=ligth;
                    color_n4b=neutro;
                    color_n5b=ligth; 
                    color_n6b=ligth;
                    color_n7b=ligth; 
            break;
            default:
                    color_n1b=neutro;
                    color_n2b=neutro; 
                    color_n3b=neutro;
                    color_n4b=neutro;
                    color_n5b=neutro; 
                    color_n6b=neutro;
                    color_n7b=neutro; 
            break;
        }
        switch (left){
            case 1:
                    color_n1a=neutro;
                    color_n2a=neutro; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=neutro;
                    color_n5a=neutro; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=neutro; 
            break; 
            case 2:
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=neutro; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=ligth;
                    color_n5a=ligth; 
                    color_n6a=neutro;
                    color_n7a=ligth;
            break;
            case 3: 
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=neutro; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=ligth;
                    color_n5a=neutro; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=ligth;
            break;
            case 4: 
                    color_n1a=neutro;
                    color_n2a=ligth; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=ligth;
                    color_n5a=neutro; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=neutro;
            break; 
            case 5:
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=ligth; 
                    color_n3a=neutro;
                    color_n4a=ligth;
                    color_n5a=neutro; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=ligth;
            break;
            case 6: 
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=ligth; 
                    color_n3a=neutro;
                    color_n4a=ligth;
                    color_n5a=ligth; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=ligth;
            break;
            case 7:
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=neutro; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=neutro;
                    color_n5a=neutro; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=neutro;
            break;
            case 8:
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=ligth; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=ligth;
                    color_n5a=ligth; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=ligth;
            break;
            case 9:
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=ligth; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=ligth;
                    color_n5a=neutro; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=ligth;
            break;
            case 0:
                    color_n1a=ligth;
                    color_n2a=ligth; 
                    color_n3a=ligth;
                    color_n4a=neutro;
                    color_n5a=ligth; 
                    color_n6a=ligth;
                    color_n7a=ligth;
            break;
            default:
                    color_n1a=neutro;
                    color_n2a=neutro; 
                    color_n3a=neutro;
                    color_n4a=neutro;
                    color_n5a=neutro; 
                    color_n6a=neutro;
                    color_n7a=neutro; 
            break;
        }
    }       





    if(cadena.length()==1){
        color_n1a=ligth;
        color_n2a=ligth; 
        color_n3a=ligth;
        color_n4a=neutro;
        color_n5a=ligth; 
        color_n6a=ligth;
        color_n7a=ligth;

        if(numero==1){
            color_n1b=neutro;
            color_n2b=neutro; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=neutro;
            color_n5b=neutro; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=neutro; 

        } else if(numero==2){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=neutro; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=ligth;
            color_n5b=ligth; 
            color_n6b=neutro;
            color_n7b=ligth;

        } else if(numero==3){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=neutro; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=ligth;
            color_n5b=neutro; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=ligth;

        } else if(numero==4){
            color_n1b=neutro;
            color_n2b=ligth; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=ligth;
            color_n5b=neutro; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=neutro; 
        } else if(numero==5){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=ligth; 
            color_n3b=neutro;
            color_n4b=ligth;
            color_n5b=neutro; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=ligth;

        } else if(numero==6){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=ligth; 
            color_n3b=neutro;
            color_n4b=ligth;
            color_n5b=ligth; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=ligth;

        } else if(numero==7){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=neutro; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=neutro;
            color_n5b=neutro; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=neutro;

        } else if(numero==8){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=ligth; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=ligth;
            color_n5b=ligth; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=ligth;

        } else if(numero==9){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=ligth; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=ligth;
            color_n5b=neutro; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=ligth; 

        } else if(numero==0){
            color_n1b=ligth;
            color_n2b=ligth; 
            color_n3b=ligth;
            color_n4b=neutro;
            color_n5b=ligth; 
            color_n6b=ligth;
            color_n7b=ligth;

        } 


    }

}

//metodo que retorna el numero que improme el timeligth
public int getNumber() {

    return numero;
}

//metodo que pone el reloj en una forma de espera
public void waited() {

    color_n1a=neutro;
    color_n2a=neutro; 
    color_n3a=neutro;
    color_n4a=ligth;
    color_n5a=neutro; 
    color_n6a=neutro;
    color_n7a=neutro;

    color_n1b=neutro;
    color_n2b=neutro; 
    color_n3b=neutro;
    color_n4b=ligth;
    color_n5b=neutro; 
    color_n6b=neutro;
    color_n7b=neutro;

}

//cambia el color de las celdas cuando estan prendidas
public void setColorLigth(Color color_luz) {
    this.ligth=color_luz;
}

//retorna el color de las celdas encendidas
public Color getColorLigth() {

    return ligth;
}

//cambia el color del cuadrado principañ
public void setColorFound(Color color_fondo) {
    this.cuadrado_principal=color_fondo; 
}

//retorna el color del cuadrado_principal
public Color getColorFound() {
    return cuadrado_principal;
}

//cambiia el color de las celdas cuando estan apagadas
public void setColorLow(Color color_celdas) {
    this.neutro=color_celdas;
}

//retorna el color de las celdas cuando estan apagadas
public Color getColorLow() {
    return neutro; 
}



//metodo principal dibuja a los componentes
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    g.setColor(cuadrado_principal); 
    g.fillRect(X,Y,ancho_total,alto_total); 

    g.setColor(color_n1a);  //n1a
    g.fillRoundRect(n1ax, n1ay, n1a_ancho, n1a_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n2a);
    g.fillRoundRect(n2ax, n2ay, n2a_ancho, n2a_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n3a);
    g.fillRoundRect(n3ax, n3ay, n3a_ancho, n3a_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n4a);
    g.fillRoundRect(n4ax, n4ay, n4a_ancho, n4a_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n5a);
    g.fillRoundRect(n5ax, n5ay, n5a_ancho, n5a_alto, roun1, roun2); 

    g.setColor(color_n6a);
    g.fillRoundRect(n6ax, n6ay, n6a_ancho, n6a_alto, roun1, roun2); 

    g.setColor(color_n7a);
    g.fillRoundRect(n7ax, n7ay, n7a_ancho, n7a_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n1b);
    g.fillRoundRect(n1bx, n1by, n1b_ancho, n1a_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n2b);
    g.fillRoundRect(n2bx, n2by, n2b_ancho, n2b_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n3b);
    g.fillRoundRect(n3bx, n3by, n3b_ancho, n3b_alto, roun1, roun2); 

    g.setColor(color_n4b);
    g.fillRoundRect(n4bx, n4by, n4b_ancho, n4b_alto, roun1, roun2); 

    g.setColor(color_n5b);
    g.fillRoundRect(n5bx, n5by, n5b_ancho, n5b_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n6b);
    g.fillRoundRect(n6bx, n6by, n6b_ancho, n6b_alto, roun1, roun2);

    g.setColor(color_n7b); 
    g.fillRoundRect(n7bx, n7by, n7b_ancho, n7b_alto, roun1, roun2);







}



}
```

les agradeceria su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente especifica en tu layour donde quieres que se pinten, por ejemplo si usas border layout puedes usar:

```
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f.add(boton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
f.add(time, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Y tu resultado se verá algo así:

[image: ejemplo con border layout]

(El botón no tiene ni texto ni nada porque ese código no lo compartiste)