# No consigo que se vea un JLabel dentro de un JDialog

Tags: jlabel, jdialog

Estoy probando a introducir componentes Java con código, no con el diseñador, que así si me funcionan. El caso es que con el diseñador puedo poner *JLabel* dentro de un *JDialog*, pero con código no consigo que el *JLabel* se muestre.

Os pongo el código, es muy simple en realidad:

```
public class Tablero extends java.awt.Dialog {
public Tablero(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();

    this.setVisible(true);               
    

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("PRUEBA");
    
    panelTablero.add(label);
    panelTablero.setVisible(true);
    

    //formarCasillero();
}
```

¿Alguien me puede dar una idea de porque no sé ve el *JLabel*?

Gracias por anticipado.

Un saludo

Comment: Tu ejemplo no compila por las siguientes razones: panelTablero no está definido, el método initComponents tampoco está definido. Saludos.

Comment: De igual manera te recomiendo revisar mi respuesta a la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316160/mi-objeto-no-se-dibuja-en-mi-jframe creo que podría serte de ayuda

Comment: A ver, solo he puesto el trozo de código que interesaba para la pregunta, por supuesto que se compila y se ejecuta, tiene todo lo necesario. Simplemente que no veo el JLabel situado dentro del JPanel que está dentro del JDialog. Solo eso. Pero si puedo ejcutarlo, me presenta en panel vacío.

Comment: He revisado la respuesta a la otra pregunta, tal como dices, pero es que no tiene nada que ver con lo que yo he preguntado, ni se parece. De todos modos, gracias. Seguiré intentándolo. un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya lo he solucionado. Tan solo hay que poner el this.setVisible(true), el que se refiere al JDialog, después de la creación de la etiqueta y de añadirla al panel, con eso se visualiza. De hecho el método setVisible en el panel sobra también, el código queda más sencillo.

```
    public Tablero(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
   
    JLabel label = new JLabel("PRUEBA");
    panelTablero.add(label);
    this.setVisible(true);               

}
```

Espero que a alguien que le pase lo mismo le pueda valer.
Un saludo